# Framer-motion does not apply exit condition correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, framer-motion

Working example (which for some reason deos not work, some syntax error regarding import stack something happens):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  motion,
  AnimatePresence
} from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(null);

  const cards = ["Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3"]; // Replace with your actual data

  return ( <
    AnimatePresence >
    <
    div className = "cards" > {
      cards.map((card, index) => ( <
        motion.div className = "card"
        key = {
          index
        }
        onClick = {
          () => setSelectedCard(index)
        }
        animate = {
          selectedCard === index ? {
            opacity: 1
          } : {
            opacity: 0
          }
        }
        exit = {
          {
            display: "none"
          }
        }
        transition = {
          {
            duration: 0.5
          }
        } > {
          card
        } <
        /motion.div>
      ))
    } <
    /div> < /
    AnimatePresence >
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.cards {
  display: flexbox;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 5px solid #ff0000;
  /* Set the color you want for the outline */
  width: 7rem;
}

.card {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 2px solid #5d00ff;
  /* Set the color you want for the outline */
  width: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I would assume that after clicking on any card in the right side box, the rest of them would be rendered out of the dom, but it does not happen, they just stay hidden (opacity 0)

I did specify exit condition for motion as display: "none"

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/q9693v?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A9%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8xv24z00062a66sbwo8ajv%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8xv24z00022a66mbj64g2m%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8xv24z00032a66kbutnadc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8xv24z00052a66wkj1q33t%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr8xv24z00022a66mbj64g2m%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8xv24z00022a66mbj64g2m%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.eslintrc.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8y51r500yn2a66q6la7tql%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8ypqgm00022a66n3sstjbs%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles.css%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr8ypqgm00022a66n3sstjbs%2522%257D%252C%2522clr8xv24z00052a66wkj1q33t%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8xv24z00052a66wkj1q33t%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr8yqnhi009o2a66fnujh810%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8yqnhi009o2a66fnujh810%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clr8xv24z00032a66kbutnadc%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8xv24z00032a66kbutnadc%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr8yn8d700x52a66pyxb0jlz%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr8yn8d700x52a66pyxb0jlz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: What effect are you going for? The main reason your exit animation isn't working is because the card isn't being removed from the React tree. I made [this example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/frosty-pare-forked-r2lnxq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A11%2C28), but not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, so now I understand how removing an element form the Dom actually works, basically changing the key is what determines it

Comment: What I wanna do is to have all cards initially visible and when I click on any of them, the others to fade out and be removed from the Dom. Reclicking on the selected card would fade in the removed cards back to the page

Comment: But, all in all, ur example thought me enough to get by, so if you'd like to submit it as answer it does solve my problem!

Comment: yes, changing a key can tell React to rerender an element. You can also use React state to conditionally render an element. I've updated my example with an effect that I think is close to what you're looking for. I'll post it in my answer.

Comment: Yup, exactly how I did it myself based on ur initial example, apreciate you and ur time, thank you very much, you don't even know how much it helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason your exit animation isn't working is because the card isn't being removed from the React tree. I've made [this example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/framer-motion-animate-presence-filter-r2lnxq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js) with something close to the effect you are going for.